# How to add in boostrap in fixed-top bar icons like facebook jewel-icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and fixed-top navigation bar, how can I add icons like in Facebook navigation bar (icons: friends, messages, notifications) to navbar ? I have icons in PNG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built in icons in bootstrap called [Glyphicons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons). You can use those icons.
You can also use your own icons if you want, you just need to put the image inside the navigation list.
Here is an example:

```css
.my-icon {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Facebook</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">      
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
      </form>     
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#"><img class="my-icon" src="http://images.onlinelabels.com/images/clip-art/acspike/acspike_male_user_icon.png" /> Friends<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Messages</a></li>     
        <li><a href="#"><span class="badge">4</span> Notifications</a></li> 
      </ul>    
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks, is there any problem, if I have my own icons in PNG files ?

Comment: Nope, its very easy to put your own icons. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you got the div written and you want to stick it to the top or the bottom use this class:

```
navbar-fixed-top //this class sticks the div to the top
```

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbfputnn/4/)